# Aggregate production function and returns to scale

Tags: production-function, capital-returns, aggregate-production

I have following Aggregate production function -

$$ Ak_1^\alpha l_1^{1-\alpha} +  Ak_2^\alpha l_2^{1-\alpha}$$

Individually each part exhibit constant returns to scale but as an Aggregate function function, does it also exhibit CRS. How to check for Returns to scale in Aggregate production function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming that you are interested in finding the aggregate production function when you have two plants and they use same inputs. So if you have $k$ units of capital and $l$ units of labor in total, how to allocate these in two plants to get the aggregate production function as a function of $k$ and $l$. In this problem, you can first find the aggregate production function by solving this problem:

\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{(k_1, k_2, l_1, l_2) \in \mathbb{R}^4_+} & Ak_1^\alpha l_1^{1-\alpha} + Ak_2^\alpha l_2^{1-\alpha} \\ \text{s.t} \ & k_1+ k_2 = k \\ \text{and} \ & l_1+ l_2 = l\end{eqnarray*}
and you'll get the aggregate production function $f(k, l)$ which is the optimal value of the objective function in the above problem.
Solving the above problem, we'll get $k_1 = k_2 = \frac{k}{2}$ and $l_1 = l_2 = \frac{l}{2}$ as one of the solutions and therefore, $f(k, l) = Ak^\alpha l^{1-\alpha}$ which satisfy CRS.

Comment: Thank you @Amit sir! What if $$k_1≠k_2 and l_1≠l_2$$ ? How will we check for Returns to scale then? Thanks a ton

Comment: It is one of the solutions to the above problem. There are other solutions and of course they'll all result in the same aggregate production function. For example: $k_1 = l_1 = 0$ and $k_2 = k, l_2 = l$ also solves the maximisation problem.

Comment: My question is not about solution or does checking returns to scale depends on solution? Does the aggregate function, in its current form, exhibit CRS?

Comment: What you have written is not the aggregate production function. Anyways, if we think of $k_1$ and $k_2$ as different types of capital and $l_1$ and $l_2$ as different types of labor i.e. there are four inputs. In that case, we can write the aggregate production function as $F(l_1, k_1, l_2, k_2) = Ak_1^\alpha l_1^{1-\alpha} + Ak_2^\alpha l_2^{1-\alpha}$, and this function also clearly exhibits CRS.

Comment: Basically, $k_1$ and $k_2$ are capital given to two individuals such that $k_1 + k_2 = k$ while $l_1$ and $l_2$ are labor inputs of two individuals. They both are producing separately and Aggregate production function, given above, summates the output produced by them. So, how can check returns of scale under such Aggregate production function where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are not different/separate types of capital.

Comment: If your objective is to maximise the total production and want to allocate inputs to them accordingly, then you can use $f(k, l)$. If you have no such objective then you can consider the function $F(l_1, k_1, l_2, k_2)$ if you want.

Comment: So, when I use f(k,l) then can I solve it assuming CRS because separately production function exhibits CRS? Or Do the power of inputs should be $\alpha/2$ and $(1-\alpha)/2$ for it to be CRS?

Comment: I haven't understood your question.

Comment: My problem is - do we check for CRS by adding the powers of each input, like here $ 2 [\alpha + (1-\alpha)] > 1$. That will make the production function IRS. Or do we add the power of of separate production function $ [\alpha + (1-\alpha)] $ and take them out as common as in $\lambda^{\alpha + (1-\alpha)} $ which will make above function CRS.

Comment: Why will you add the powers like this? Just read the definition of CRS and apply it here and you'll know. It is easy.

Comment: Because CRS requires output to double when $all$ the inputs double. Here summing over each input power with the base 2 more than doubles the output. Isn't that the correct definition of CRS?

Comment: Definition is correct but you are not applying it correctly.

Comment: So, correct way is $$\lambda^{\alpha + 1- \alpha}(Ak_1^\alpha l_1^{1-\alpha} + Ak_2^\alpha l_2^{1-\alpha}) $$ which makes the production function CRS. We did this because when inputs gets doubled their individual was CRS and Aggregate would just double everything as well. Is my reasoning correct now?

Comment: Yes it is correct

Comment: Thank you sir for all the help!